# The Quintessential Quintuplets: Is Fuutarou's theme supposed to be like Survivor's Eye of the Tiger?

Tags: soundtrack, instrumental, similar-artists

This is about a track in the OST of the anime [The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quintessential_Quintuplets).

Listen to

0:00 - 0:03 in Fuutarou's theme

and then to

0:09 - 0:11 in Survivor's Eye of the Tiger

I read some comments that say

> it is the same chord progression.

I wasn't able to find anything when googling "hanayome" "eye of the tiger" or "quintessential quintuplets" "eye of the tiger" though.

1. Maybe there's some Japanese site that says Fuutaro's theme is supposed to be like or samples or whatever Eye of the Tiger? (I ask this in anime stackexchange: [Is Fuutarou's theme supposed to be like Survivor's Eye of the Tiger?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66643/is-fuutarous-theme-supposed-to-be-like-survivors-eye-of-the-tiger))
2. Is it the same chord progression?

Answer (score 1):

The first bar of each chord progression has the same rhythm and a moves down a whole step and back up, but that's where the similarity ends. In the first example the first chord is major and in the second one it's minor. After the first bar both progressions go in different directions, although they both go to a chord two whole steps down at different times.
Whether the similarities are intentional is a matter of opinion. Even if they were intentional the authors certainly wouldn't admit it because they would want to avoid claims of plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks PiedPiper! (Strangely this answer did not show up in my notifications.) Wait why plagiarism? I think it could be like, what, sampling? Like cheers by Rihanna samples Avril Lavigne's I'm With You ?

Comment: There's no sampling going on here.

Comment: Not sure of the term sampling. Maybe referencing? Parodying?

Comment: It's not a parody either. As I wrote, it's possible the reference in the first bar of that progression was intentional, but it's unlikely to be enough to qualify as copyright infringement.

Comment: Of course I don't think it's copyright infringement, which is why I was wondering about your statement here 'Even if they were intentional the authors certainly wouldn't admit it because they would want to avoid claims of plagiarism.' What's up with that?

Comment: Is the composer says "I copied this" that's an admission of plagiarism.

Comment: PiedPiper how come  Rihanna can do it re Avril? (And whatever answer you give, why can't TQQ do it re Survivor? And if they can, they how do you know [Gasai] that's not what they did?)

Comment: If you're talking about sampling (which is not the case here): sometimes you can get away with it, sometimes you can't. https://www.vondranlegal.com/five-music-infringement-cases-mixingsampling

Comment: ok thanks PiedPiper, so you mean that in your understanding this is either intentional and thus REALLY plagiarism or simply coincidental, like no 3rd option?